# SQL subqueries optimisation, how to execute subquery first

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have an optimisation issue I would like to execute the subquery first

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT * 
  FROM `References_galaxia`
     , Link_galaxia 
 WHERE linkReferenced IN ( SELECT id 
                             FROM Link_galaxia 
                            WHERE idConceptStart IN (616269,616268,615721) 
                              AND idConceptLink = 315 
                              AND idConceptTarget = 29209 
                         ) 
   AND `References_galaxia`.linkReferenced = Link_galaxia.id 
   AND `References_galaxia`.idConcept IN (416,36053,36088,36037)
```

The main query returns a hudge amount of data about a million records onto memory. While the subquery

> SELECT id FROM Link_galaxia WHERE idConceptStart IN
>   (616269,616268,615721) AND idConceptLink = 315 AND idConceptTarget =
>   29209 )

Return a little amount of data. How to manage to execute the subquery first ?

The result of Explain

```
1   PRIMARY References_galaxia  ALL unique_ref,linkReferenced   NULL    NULL    NULL    9163156 Using where
1   PRIMARY Link_galaxia    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   eds_sandra.References_galaxia.linkReferenced    1   
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  Link_galaxia    eq_ref  PRIMARY,idx_name,idConceptStart,idConceptStart_4,idConceptTarget,idConceptLink  PRIMARY 4   References_galaxia.linkReferenced   1   Using where
```

Thank you a lot for your help !

Comment: You don't seem to like the word 'JOIN' too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query such as the following would appear to be more optimal:

```
SELECT columns, I, actually, want
  FROM `References_galaxia` r
  JOIN Link_galaxia x
    ON x.id = r.linkreferenced
  JOIN Link_galaxia y
    ON y.id = r.linkReferenced 
 WHERE r.idConcept IN (416,36053,36088,36037)
   AND y.idConceptStart IN (616269,616268,615721) 
   AND y.idConceptLink = 315 
   AND y.idConceptTarget = 29209
```

For help on improving the performance of this query, we would need to see table creation statements for all relevant tables, as well as the EXPLAIN.

Comment: Great ! Woks like a charm

Comment: I must admit I like the original query better - apart from that antiquated join syntax of course. I think the `IN` clause makes it more readable. But it seems, MySQL still has a weak point with `IN` clauses. I thought they had finally managed to handle them better. @user3032887: What version are you using?

Comment: We use version 5.1.49

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `References_galaxia`
     , Link_galaxia 
 WHERE `References_galaxia`.linkReferenced = Link_galaxia.id 
   AND `References_galaxia`.idConcept IN (416,36053,36088,36037)
   AND Link_galaxia.idConceptStart IN (616269,616268,615721) 
   AND Link_galaxia.idConceptLink = 315 
   AND Link_galaxia.idConceptTarget = 29209
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run modified subquery and store ID in variable

```
SELECT id INTO @idvar FROM Link_galaxia 
                     WHERE idConceptStart IN (616269,616268,615721) 
                     AND idConceptLink = 315 
                     AND idConceptTarget = 29209
```

And include this var (@idvar) into your main SQL

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `References_galaxia`
     , Link_galaxia 
 WHERE linkReferenced IN @idvar 
  AND `References_galaxia`.linkReferenced = Link_galaxia.id 
  AND `References_galaxia`.idConcept IN (416,36053,36088,36037);
```

Complete code can be with transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT id INTO @idvar FROM Link_galaxia 
                         WHERE idConceptStart IN (616269,616268,615721) 
                         AND idConceptLink = 315 
                         AND idConceptTarget = 29209;
SELECT * 
  FROM `References_galaxia`
     , Link_galaxia 
 WHERE linkReferenced IN @idvar 
  AND `References_galaxia`.linkReferenced = Link_galaxia.id 
  AND `References_galaxia`.idConcept IN (416,36053,36088,36037);
COMMIT;
```